# Marking South migrations as new

Tags: django, migration, django-south

I accidentally ran faked South migrations for an app using the `--fake` option, but the database is missing the last change.

I faked three migrations, but the database state is still at 0002. If you list the migrations, all migrations are marked as run.

```
$ ./manage.py migrate cmsplugin_mailchimp --list

 cmsplugin_mailchimp
  (*) 0001_initial
  (*) 0002_thankyou_field
  (*) 0003_redirect_url
```

Is there a way to mark the latest migration as new, so that it gets processed when I run `./manage.py migrate cmsplugin_mailchimp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no extra option to "mark a migration as new", but there is a different, quite obvious solution: Simply do a backwards migration.

```
$ ./manage.py migrate cmsplugin_mailchimp 0002 --fake

 - Soft matched migration 0002 to 0002_thankyou_field.
Running migrations for cmsplugin_mailchimp:
 - Migrating backwards to just after 0002_thankyou_field.
 < cmsplugin_mailchimp:0003_redirect_url
   (faked)

$ ./manage.py migrate cmsplugin_mailchimp --list

 cmsplugin_mailchimp
  (*) 0001_initial
  (*) 0002_thankyou_field
  ( ) 0003_redirect_url
```

Now the state of South matches the state of the database, and you can actually run the last migration::

```
$ ./manage.py migrate cmsplugin_mailchimp

Running migrations for cmsplugin_mailchimp:
 - Migrating forwards to 0003_redirect_url.
 > cmsplugin_mailchimp:0003_redirect_url
 - Loading initial data for cmsplugin_mailchimp.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```